# how to destruc an object which includes a long string with dot as the key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I have an object which includes string with dot "journey.hintText.journeyTags" as the key. (returned by api response i cannot modify). I would like to destruct content object like const {journey.hintText.journeyTags} = content, but it throws error. Please let me know how I can destruct content object, thanks a lot.

```
const content = {journey.hintText.journeyTags: 'Please select a tag'}
```

Comment: `delete content['journey.hintText.journeyTags']`

Comment: Sorry I closed this by mistake, this is about de-structuring, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed properties, but you should provide the name like this `const { ['journey.hintText.journeyTags']: journeyTags } = content`